# Using sqlmock to return nil for query execution in Golang

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, mocking, go-sqlmock

I am using `sqlmock` to mock a Snowflake query execution. This may look strange, but for the following query:

```
rows, err = db.Query(sqlQuery)
```

I need the mock to return `nil` for both `rows` and `err`. Notice I want `nil` for `rows` not an empty set. Here is my function. I tried the statements in comments as well.

```
func mockSnowflake(t *testing.T, sqlQuery string) (*sql.DB, sqlmock.Sqlmock) {
    db, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
    // 5 is because I'll be calling db.Query() 5 times
    for i := 1; i <= 5; i++ {
        //mock.ExpectQuery(sqlQuery).WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows(nil))
        //mock.ExpectQuery(sqlQuery).WillReturnRows(sqlmock.NewRows([]string {"Test Column"}).AddRow(nil))
        mock.ExpectQuery(sqlQuery).WillReturnRows(nil)
    }
    return db, mock
}
```

How should I change the function?

Comment: have you tried `mock.ExpectQuery(sqlQuery).WillReturnError(nil)`?